# Facebook Live API: delete a live video

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, publish-actions, live-video

I've created a live video thru the Faceboook API (v3.1, all latest changes are implemented) and it works ok for me.
When I'm trying to deletethe video using the call:

```
DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/{live_video_id}?access_token=token 
-----------------------
"error": {
    "message": "(#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "Dcl7arp3pts"
}
```

Why? I've requested all need permissions already in the oAuth login ("publish_video",
            "publish_pages",
            "manage_pages",
            "user_managed_groups",
            "user_friends",
            "public_profile",
            "user_videos" ) otherwise I had not possible to create the live video.

Comment: There’s already a couple of reports on similar bugs, see if those match your case: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/295092697738756/, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/261018148000036/

Comment: Yeah, I've reported them too.